# Borel-Weil-Bott theorem vs the usual formula

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, projective-space, sheaf-cohomology

I am confused about the Borel-Weil-Bott theorem.

For example, if I try to compute $H^i(\mathbb{P}^5,\mathcal{O}(-8)),$ Borel-Weil-Bott computation is the following:

1. Find the sequence: $\sigma= (0,0,0,0,0,8)+(6,5,4,3,2,1)=(6,5,4,3,2,9)$
2. There are no repetitions, so not all cohomologies are zero.
3. There are 5 'disarrangements', that is, in this sequence there are 5 pairs of numbers that are not decreasing.
4. We should sort $\sigma$: $\tilde{\sigma}=(9,6,5,4,3,2)$ and subtract $(6,5,4,3,2,1)$, the result is $(3,1,1,1,1,1).$
5. Finally, the answer is $H^5(\mathbb{P}^5,\mathcal{O}(-8))=W_{(3,1,1,1,1,1)}.$

But we know that $H^5(\mathbb{P}^5,\mathcal{O}(-8))=Sym^2(V)=W_{(2,0,0,0,0,0)}.$

I don't understand why the results are different.

Comment: The results are not so different. If I understand your notation correctly,
$ W_{(3,1,1,1,1,1)} = {\rm Sym}^2 (V) \otimes{\rm det}(V).$
But ${\rm det}(V)$ is a vector space of dimension one, so $W_{(3,1,1,1,1,1)}$ has the same dimension as ${\rm Sym}^2(V)$.

Comment: Yes, I understand that in Borel-Weil-Bott case there's tensor product with det(V) but I don't understand where it comes from. I agree that the dimension is the same but as representations these two are different while I was expecting the same answer.

Comment: I wonder if there is a simple way to explain why $H^5(\mathbb P^5, \mathcal O(-6)) = {\rm det}(V)$? Maybe it helps to identify $H^5(\mathbb P^5, \mathcal O(-6))$ as the one-dimensional vector space spanned by the monomial $x_0^{-1} \dots x_5^{-1}$? We can think of $x_0^{-1} \dots x_5^{-1}$ as a section of $\mathcal O(-6)$ on the open subset $U_{x_0 \dots x_5}$ (following the notation in Hartshorne III 5.1), which represents a Cech cohomology class. Maybe we can think about what this Cech cohomology class looks like when written in terms of another basis for the $\mathbb C^6$?

Comment: One way to see that $H^5({\mathbb P}^5,{\mathcal O}(-6)) = \det V$ is via the Koszul complex: $0 \to {\mathcal O}(-6) \to V \otimes {\mathcal O}(-5) \to \Lambda^2V \otimes {\mathcal O}(-4) \to \dots \to \Lambda^5V \otimes {\mathcal O}(-1) \to \Lambda^6V \otimes {\mathcal O} \to 0$.

Comment: The point is whether you want to consider the cohomology as representations of $SL(V)$ or $GL(V)$. The BBW gives the canonical $GL(V)$ structure, while the identification $H^5 = Sym^2(V)$ is only correct on $SL(V)$ level. And as representations of $SL(V)$, of course, $W_{(3,1,1,1,1,1)} \cong W_{(2,0,0,0,0,0)}$, since $\det(V)$ is trivial.